# Importing CSV with record order intact

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013, excel-2013

I'm trying to achieve what I understand should be a fairly simple task, but I'm just not seeing how to fix it.

I have a database in Excel, which I would like to also have in Access, keeping the .xls as a master file (not my choice, this is what I've been told to do). My current thought process is that a user can save the Excel database as a .CSV (this preserves the "look" of custom formatting used quite frequently in the Excel sheet), then open Access and hit a command button which will import the CSV, overwriting/updating data in an already existing table.The basic import code for Access is:

```
Function ImportLineLists()
    DoCmd.DeleteObject Table, "__"
    DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "__", _
    "__", "__"
End Function
```

Where __  is just where I've omitted actual file/table names as they include slightly sensitive info. My issue is that when I import the CSV using this function, it ignores the primary key I setup in the import spec (not creating a field for it at all, when it appears in the CSV normally), and indents the fields by 1 column.

E.g:      [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fk0mr.png)

The IDNUM field gets deleted/omitted, and its values are moved across to the Site Code field. Am I missing something extremely obvious? Any help is much appreciated! (:

Comment: Why not just link the csv file? Then you don't have to delete anything, and if you run the import/link wizard adjusting settings for the fields, these will be preserved when you replace the csv file.

Comment: And - referring to the title - there is, per definition, no order of the records in a table, only the order you define yourself. So create a simple select query to pull the data from the linked table and define basic sorting, filtering, and converting in this. Then use this query for all your further processing.

Comment: Knew I was missing something simple! I'd dismissed the idea of linking in my head as it didn't preserve the formatting from excel, so never came back to that for the csv's.

Thanks a lot, appreciate the help!